# How to get local timezone name?

Tags: flutter, dart, timezone

I want get local time zone name like "Asia/Tokyo"

I tried

```
DateTime.now().timeZoneName
```

This gives value like +0530. Is there a way to get the time zone name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [timezone](https://pub.dev/packages/timezone) package. You can get time zone names from the [IANA Time Zone Database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) with this package. It should look like this:

```
Future<void> initTimezones() async {
    // get device timezone
    String dtz = await FlutterNativeTimezone.getLocalTimezone();

    // Load timezone data
    var byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/timezone/2020a.tzf');
    tz.initializeDatabase(byteData.buffer.asUint8List());
    tz.initializeTimeZones();
    // set the local location.
    tz.setLocalLocation(tz.getLocation(dtz));

    // Iterate and use through the list of timezones.
    _locations = tz.timeZoneDatabase.locations;
    _locations.values.forEach((element) {
        print(element.name);
        print(element.currentTimeZone.abbr);
        print(element.currentTimeZone.offset);
        print(element.currentTimeZone.isDst);
        print(element.zones.length);
      });
  }
```

There are some helpful [links](https://dev.to/shaileshs/using-timezone-package-in-flutter-2cln) about [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/working-with-timezones-in-flutter-1c304089dcf9).

The read.me file shows how to get the timezone name:

```
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;

void main() {
  tz.initializeTimeZones();
  var locations = tz.timeZoneDatabase.locations;
  print(locations.length); // => 429
  print(locations.keys.first); // => "Africa/Abidjan"
  print(locations.keys.last); // => "US/Pacific"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TimeZone names as the required format - 'Asia/Tokyo' require downloaded library files, package or API services. If reliability is not important you may try this Flutter [package](https://pub.dev/packages/timezone) or use more reliable [TimeZone API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/overview) from Google. It will require latitude, longitude for providing timeZoneId and other necessary details.

Answer (score 0):

By using below package and code, you can simply achieve local timezone.

https://pub.dev/packages/timezone

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_timezone/versions

```
import 'package:flutter_native_timezone/flutter_native_timezone.dart';


   getTimeZone() async {
     final String currentTimeZone = await FlutterNativeTimezone.getLocalTimezone();
     print(currentTimeZone); // Asia/Kolkata
   }
```